# How do I get mouse position with tkinter and turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a program that lets me draw on a tkinter window using turtle. For some reason I cannot get the absolute mouse coordinates.

I have done `root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()` (and `vrootx`). 
I have also tried:

```
def mousePos(event):
     x,y = event.x , event.y
     return x,y
```

My code:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Draw!")
cv = tk.Canvas(root, width=500,height=500)
cv.focus_set()
cv.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
pen = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
window = pen.getscreen()

def main():
    window.setworldcoordinates(-500,-500,500,500)
    window.bgcolor("white")
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.BOTH)
    pointLabel = tk.Label(frame,text="Width")
    pointLabel.pack()
    def getPosition(event):
       x = root.winfo_pointerx()-root.winfo_vrootx()
       y = root.winfo_pointery()-root.winfo_vrooty()
       pen.goto(x,y)
    cv.bind("<Motion>", getPosition)
    cv.pack
    tk.mainloop()
    pass
```

I want the cursor to be on top of the arrow, but instead it is always to the right and down. Also, when I move the mouse up, the arrow moves down, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think hard about how you set the setworldcoordinate(). -500 - 500 means your world has 1,000 in size and window size is 500. Also, the mouse pointer offset from the window root - both absolute coordinates should be used. You mixed up the absolute coordinates - mouse pointer and vrootx which is in different scale so the distance of two makes no sense. Following code is probably closer to what you intended. Note that, I set the world coordinate to match the absolute coordinates of mouse pointer offset from the top/left corner of window.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Draw!")
cv = tk.Canvas(root, width=500,height=500)
cv.focus_set()
cv.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
pen = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
window = pen.getscreen()

def main():
    window.setworldcoordinates(0,500,500,0)
    window.bgcolor("white")
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.BOTH)
    pointLabel = tk.Label(frame,text="Width")
    pointLabel.pack()
    print(dir(root))
    def getPosition(event):
       x = root.winfo_pointerx()-root.winfo_rootx()
       y = root.winfo_pointery()-root.winfo_rooty()
       print(x, y)
       pen.goto(x,y)
       pass
    cv.bind("<Motion>", getPosition)
    cv.pack
    tk.mainloop()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
  pass
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my system -- the mouse only somewhat tracks the cursor but also flys about a bit on its own and the program soon fails with a "Python quit unexpectedly" popup panel and an "Abort" to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an issue working against you that isn't of your own making.  The general rule is when in a turtle canvas, use turtle methods.  But turtle doesn't have an inherent 'Motion' event type, so you were trying to use the raw `Canvas` one as a substitute.  Thus the conflict.

An issue of your own making is that when you're inside a fast moving event handler, you need to disable the event hander as the first thing you do, reenabling on exit.  Otherwise, events overlap and bad things happen.  (Inadvertant recursions and other wierdness.)

I've rewritten your program below to work as I believe you intended.  The fix is adding the missing turtle method so we can stay within the turtle domain:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
from functools import partial

def onscreenmove(self, fun, add=None):  # method missing from turtle.py

    if fun is None:
        self.cv.unbind('<Motion>')
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(self.cv.canvasx(event.x) / self.xscale, -self.cv.canvasy(event.y) / self.yscale)

        self.cv.bind('<Motion>', eventfun, add)

def getPosition(x, y):
    screen.onscreenmove(None)  # disable events inside handler

    pen.setheading(pen.towards(x, y))
    pen.goto(x, y)

    screen.onscreenmove(getPosition)  # reenable handler on exit

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Draw!")

cv = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
cv.focus_set()
cv.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

screen = TurtleScreen(cv)
screen.onscreenmove = partial(onscreenmove, screen)  # install missing method

pen = RawTurtle(screen)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)

tk.Label(frame, text="Width").pack()

screen.onscreenmove(getPosition)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much, this fixed my issue and helped shorten my code. You probably guessed I am new to programming, but you explained things I didn't know about and I am grateful..

Answer (score 0):

Mouse position for Tkinter:

```py
    import Tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()

    def motion(event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))

    root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
    root.mainloop()
```

Mouse position for turtle:

```py
    canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
    x, y = canvas.winfo_pointerx(), canvas.winfo_pointery()
```

Hope this helps.